Why do I run Linux version 5.10 after upgrading to Debian 12 instead of version 6?
I upgraded from Debian11 to D12 and cat /etc/debian_version, KDE Info Center, lsb_release -a and all other ways to show the current Debian version show and showed Debian 12. The upgrade seems to have worked just fine and I have used the system for several months (including several reboots) and over that time upgraded to Debian 12.7. There was never any error / message about the kernel and nothing is asked to be installed when running sudo apt-get dist-upgrade or sudo apt-get upgrade (except sysv-rc-conf).
Despite of all this, I'm apparently running a Linux kernel of version 5 - when running cat /proc/version it returns:

Linux version 5.10.0-17-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc-10
(Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Debian)
2.35.2) #1 SMP Debian 5.10.136-1 (2022-08-13)

Why did this happen? Aren't all methods to see the current Debian version broken if they all show version 12 if I still have a kernel of version 5 and isn't the distro-upgrade process broken as well?
I only found out when my mousewheel broke but should have broken earlier right after upgrading to Debian 12 with Wayland since xbindkeys should not work with Wayland since I then noticed gcc-10 was used here.
apt policy linux-image-amd64 shows:
linux-image-amd64:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 6.1.112-1
  Version table:
     6.10.11-1~bpo12+1 100
        100 http://ftp.XY.debian.org/debian bookworm-backports/main amd64 Packages
     6.1.112-1 500
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security bookworm-security/main amd64 Packages
     6.1.106-3 500
        500 http://ftp.XY.debian.org/debian bookworm/main amd64 Packages


That apt policy linux-image-amd64 output shows that that package is not installed. You likely have only a linux-image-5.10.0-17-amd64 package, at the time possibly pulled as a dependency of linux-image-amd64, but linux-image-amd64 was uninstalled since which means your kernel was never updated past that version.

For the record, current Debian 11 kernel as of writing is 5.10.0-33-amd64 (https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/linux-image-amd64), so it's likely been a while since you last updated your kernel, likely before you upgraded to Debian 12.

Actually, you can see the build date (2022-08-13) in the uname output, so your linux-image-amd64 must have been uninstalled not too long after that.

What type of machine is this?  Physical, a full VM, or a "thin" VM (eg OpenVZ or Virtuozzo)?  If it's one of the latter types (which many of the cheaper VM providers use) then you don't get to controly our own kernel; it's inherited from the host.  If it's a full VM or a physical host then this, of course, doesn't apply; you control your own kernel.

@StephenHarris, the fact there's a KDE desktop environment and wayland and attempts to use xbindkeys suggests it's unlikely to be a VM let alone a thin one.

@StéphaneChazelas Are you saying linux-image-amd64 should not be uninstalled? I did not intend to uninstall it and didn't do so deliberately. Stephen, it's a physical desktop computer supposed to be under my full control and to be fully upgraded to Debian 12 like the version check claims it is and like the distro upgrade commands told it to. After running apt-get upgrade / installing sth it even shows Running kernel seems to be up-to-date. Another machine with exact same setup & upgrade has kernel version 6. Maybe it's due to freeing space by deleting kernel images?

Users are free to run whichever kernel they want, including kernels they build themselves; so Debian doesn’t impose installing any specific kernel packages. In fact there are many scenarios where no kernel needs to be installed (VPSes, container images, VMs with externally-managed kernels…).
However the situation you were in (where the kernel isn’t upgraded because the linux-image-amd64 package isn’t installed) is mentioned in the release notes’ section on upgrading the kernel. When upgrading Debian it’s always best to follow the release notes.

Shouldn't a new kernel be installed by default when upgrading though or the user at least be prompted about it? Could this problem have arisen because of this? I think with the situation you refer to that I did not have linux-image-amd64 installed. Please clarify if that's not what you meant. So I will sudo apt-get install linux-image-amd64 and then run the update & upgrade commands to install the latest kernel before rebooting.

In Debian, upgrades from one release to the next are managed by apt in the same way as regular upgrades, so prompting for a kernel there would mean prompting for one all the time; but there are many use-cases where kernels aren’t even needed. The user is prompted about the kernel, in the release notes. I know it’s common practice to ignore them, but they are an important part of the upgrade. The order of your commands is wrong: you should run sudo apt update && sudo apt install linux-image-amd64, no need for apt upgrade.

@mYnDstrEAm Re: "Could this problem have arisen because of this?". Yes, if at the time you run that command, you're not booted into the latest kernel (the one the linux-image-amd64 meta package currently depends upon) then that will uninstall that lastest kernel along with the meta-package. Personally, I would use aptitude for this kind of thing and select the packages to remove by hand and review the result before applying.

@StéphaneChazelas This likely answers the question about why this occurred. The command there was helpful to clear up partition disk space (which if not cleared causes the upgrade to fail or worse things) and it didn't warn about removing an essential package. It seems to have a different effect on Ubuntu but many Debian users may also find that question and this command as answer. How do you suggest this answer to be changed, just appending "Do not run this command if you run Debian." or some alternative command that also works on Debian?

You'd want to make sure you don't remove the latest kernel. To save space, that's counter productive as it would have to be reinstalled. Here, you would have had a message by apt with: "this will remove such and such" including the metapackage. Those prompts are common with apt, so you may just have ignored it without realising it would remove linux-image-amd64. I've seen much worse like people blindly removing the whole desktop stack when trying to remove a core desktop library.

It can't be assumed the user knows what "linux-image-amd64" is for. Especially not when the entire can't be used anymore due to lack of disk space or because the upgrade fails because it can't upgrade step-wise. I don't know why this command does something different on Debian than on Ubuntu. I'll edit the question to prevent other Debian users from making the same mistake so if you have any recommendation what to add or want to edit it instead please do so.

@StephenKitt So the plan to prevent other Deb users from having the same problem is to add the following to that UbuntuE answer which I'm sure many of them come across: "First run uname -sr then run {command}. Do not let it remove the kernels if any of them match the output - the command removes the latest kernel if you're not yet running the latest installed kernel (you can delete the other ones individually)." Please let me know if that is (not) fine or edit that answer directly (to add similar text or to replace the command).

@mYnDstrEAm apologies, the command given in the Ask Ubuntu answer you referenced doesn’t work on Debian because Debian kernel packages have digits in their suffixes, unlike Ubuntu kernels. I guess the real lesson there is not to assume posts on Ask Ubuntu also apply to Debian.

@StephenKitt Okay I will try to edit the answer to add a short note later and for now my comment beneath it probably somewhat warns Debian users to better not run it (it did solve my disk space issues during Deb upgrade when I used this). I think I had dkms installed before installing linux-image-amd64 (checked /var/log/ files and the recent history.log + dpkg.log don't include dkms) and now dkms recommends installing that package, was something changed about dkms so that it now recommends this package? If so this seems solved. It even asked to also install linux-headers-amd64 which I did.

@mYnDstrEAm dkms started recommending linux-headers-amd64 in 2016. It hasn’t ever recommended linux-image-amd64; it used to recommend linux-image but that was dropped in 2016. The headers recommendation was removed earlier this year, so Debian 13 will no longer have it.
